# ASP.NET Web Form on SharePoint

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

Heh guys,

I would like to create and deploy an ASP.NET web form on SharePoint server which can create document in SharePoint list (or library). Since I'm not experienced in both these technologies so would appreciate if someone guides me to the right tool. Should I use Visual Studio or SharePoint designer ? Also, I was reading an article on MSDN about "Deploying ASP.NET Web Applications in the Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 _layouts Folder". Is it the best practise or should I go with webpart/solution based deployment?

Rishi

Comment: Why do you want to create your custom page, to upload docs, instead of using the default sharepoint page?

Comment: Thanks Shoban. Actually we need to execute custom dot net code while uploading the document in SharePoint. For example, When user will upload the pdf document , using iText API I need to modify something on pdf before getting uploaded on the library.

Comment: Then why dont you write an event handler for it?

Comment: Check this link as well.. http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/Programming-Event-Handling-in-Windows-SharePoint-Services.id-306329.html

Comment: Shoban, Can you please elaborate more with some example I can refer ?

Comment: @Rishi, Check the link and it will give you some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your need, custom ListItemEventReceiver is the recommended solution.

If you are going to need an UI & reuse it in some other page, then WebPart is the way to go. Custom application page is the least preferred approach here.

An example here: http://blah.winsmarts.com/2006-7-Sharepoint_2007__List_Events_Practical_Example__Creating_a_rigged_survey.aspx

Comment: Thanks stackunderflow, Can you guide me with example where event receiver used in visual studio from scratch. The article you have mentioned is having chunk of code, I don't know how to try it at my end.

Comment: If you are using VS 2010, Create a new SharePoint Empty Project, add an EventReceiver. Select list instance to associate the receiver in development. Select events to handle such as Item Added. Open the event receiver code and uncomment method OnItemAdded and add your custom logic there.