# SharePoint help needed

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I need to write an event listener which will execute my custom C# code while uploading a document in the list. For example, When I upload a pdf document ( which is having some editable text fields ) in a list , my c# code will write some information to the pdf and it will get attached to the list.

Can someone guide me to the right direction ?

Answer (score 1):

I understnd this is connected to your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920535/asp-net-web-form-on-sharepoint) yesterday. You have also mentioned that you don't have any experience working with c#.

[This MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms442323.aspx) should get you started but I strongly advise some developer to help you if you don't have any experience working with ShrePoint.

Comment: Thanks Shoban, Unfortunately I won't get help from other devs..I will be on track with little guidance :)

Comment: @Rishi: I was like you with confidence, little guidance will help me just to find later that I have many places re invented the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianwilson/archive/2007/03/05/part-1-event-handlers-everything-you-need-to-know-about-microsoft-office-sharepoint-portal-server-moss-event-handlers.aspx) is the nice place for you to get started, this link details about what is an eventhandler,when to use it & its types.

[Refer this](http://dishasharepointworld.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-access-fields-of-list-item-in_22.html) for example on Attachment Events.

Both the above links are 2007 but it holds good for 2010 as well.